# Strategies for concurrent read/writing and reading in SQLite

Tags: concurrency, sqlite

I have an SQLite database that I am keeping open and writing to in process A. I would like to be able to use it from process B on a read-only basis.

According to [the document](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html),

- if the database is UNLOCKED the database may not be read (or written) - **unsuitable**
- if the database is SHARED then two processes can read it but the first can't write - **unsuitable**
- if a process wants to write it needs an EXCLUSIVE lock which means no other processes can write - **unsuitable**

The process A will be making lots of little writes so I don't think making a copy on each transaction commit will be efficient.

The only way I can see it is for the reader to wait until the database enters UNLOCKED state, get a SHARED lock for the duration of the read and then release it. Meanwhile process A will want to write and will be blocked until the lock becomes available - if it ever does (what if process B crashes?). This means that process A and process B will be in contention for locks - B wants SHARED and A wants EXCLUSIVE and this will slow things down or even lead to concurrency problems.

Is there any way to achieve my aim of concurrent writing and reading?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). It supports concurrent readers and one writer.

Comment: @SamiEl-Tamawy WAL model is supported from API 11. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for Android you can use WAL mode. It is (badly) supported from API 11. Better support starts with API 16. Use this code to switch your database connection to WAL mode:

```
int flags = SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY;
if(walModeEnabled) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
       flags = flags | SQLiteDatabase.ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING;
   }
}

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath.getPath(), null, flags);

// backward compatibility hack to support WAL on pre-jelly-bean devices
if(walModeEnabled) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB &&
           Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
       db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
   } else {
       Log.w(TAG, "WAL is not supported on API levels below 11.");
   }
}
```

For SQLiteOpenHelper and deeper explanation how WAL mode works under the hood please refer to my article:

https://www.skoumal.net/en/parallel-read-and-write-in-sqlite/

Answer (score -10):

Simple answer for your question is - "IMPOSSIBLE"

Even if you getting success to do so - Means you are getting wrong results.

I think you should know the basics of Database -

Why database is better then file handling and other data storage methods.

Simple answer -

You can't perform W-W, W-R, R-W operations simultaneously.

( W - write, R- read )

However you can execute infinite R-R operations at a same time.

Just think about the online Banking system or Railway reservation system.

In which there is a special feature of database is used which is Transaction.

It follows ACID.

which is Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability.

Atomicity - Either complete or not at all.

Consistency - After each transaction system will go from one consistent state to another consistent state.

Isolation - Every transaction will executed in isolation of each other.

( Means if write query come first it will executed first ) There is just no way to give both write and read operation at the same time. Even there is a difference of nano second System will detect it. However if you got success to do so . db simply reject it or execute the operation which has higher priority.

Durability - System must durable in time.

--Maybe it is very broad than a simple database but it may be help you to understand.--

2.

An SQLite database file is organized as pages. The size of each
page is a power of 2 between 512 and SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_SIZE. The default
value for SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_SIZE is 32768.

The SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT parameter, which is normally set to
1073741823, is the maximum number of pages allowed in a single database
file. An attempt to insert new data that would cause the database file
to grow larger than this will return SQLITE_FULL.

So we have 32768 * 1073741823, which is 35,184,372,056,064 (35 trillion bytes)!

You can modify SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT or SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_SIZE
in the source, but this of course will require a custom build of SQLite
for your application. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to set a
limit programmatically other than at compile time (but I'd be happy to
be proven wrong).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. First, thank you, I am acquainted with the principles of databases. Second, I think you misunderstood my question entirely. I'm not asking about the properties of databases in general, I'm asking about the issues pertaining to local file storage vs RDMS. Third, as per Doug's answer, it is possible with the Write-Ahead Log.