# SQLite : Getting database locked even for read operation

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a thread from which I am writing thousands of entries using `begin - commit` and from another thread I am trying to read from the SQLite database.

I am getting `database is locked` error while reading !!! I should be able to read as only write operations need exclusive lock.

**EDIT**

My point is that if `begin - commit` is getting RESERVED lock, another thread is still allowed to take SHARED locks, so why the another thread is not able to read at all and getting database locked error

Comment: useful? [Strategies for concurrent read/writing and reading in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117016/strategies-for-concurrent-read-writing-and-reading-in-sqlite)

Comment: @RyanVincent :  Sorry, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Have you considered that SQLite may not be the best database for your application? [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Have you checked the manual which describes locking in SQLite? It does seem that no reading is allowed when writing happens. [File Locking And Concurrency In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

Comment: @RyanVincent  : In case of `begin - commit`, RESERVED lock is acquired but multiple SHARED locks (to read) can be acuired, as per the documentation : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood.

Comment: I'm not sure how this goes in your case  but on iOS I usually get that error if i'm trying to interact with the database while it's being used. You gotta make sure it's closed before attempting to read it.

Comment: @Zil : **make sure its closed before attempting to read it?**, but its very well possible that I can keep writing from thread1, and read from another thread2, even if thread1 has not closed the db

Comment: Alright then. I'm not insanely good with databases so if you're sure it's not that then i'll walk away ^^ Just wanted to share my 2 cents and make sure you had that possibility in mind

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem or are you trying to solve a problem that must be solved using 'SQLite'?

Comment: @RyanVincent : I am struck into the problem that my DB gets locked halting all read operations till the write operations complete.