# Using FMDB: How to access sqlite in main and background thread at same time

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite, fmdb

In background thread inserting bulk data(more than 10,000 records) using `FMDatabaseQueue`

```
FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[self dbPath]];

queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db) {

    for (NSDictionary *propertyValueDictionary in customers) {
        NSString *customerId = [propertyValueDictionary objectForKey:@"CustomerId"];
        NSString *property = [propertyValueDictionary objectForKey:@"Property"];
        NSString *value =  [propertyValueDictionary objectForKey:@"Value"];
        BOOL deleted = [[propertyValueDictionary objectForKey:@"Deleted"] boolValue];
        NSString *revision = [propertyValueDictionary objectForKey:@"Revision"];

        NSString *sql = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Customer (CustomerId, Property, Value) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        [db executeUpdate:sql, customerId, property, value];

    }
}];
```

at same time, I want to read/write the sqlite in main thread without delay and blocking the UI.

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be related. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12117016/5608661